# Injecting Spring Boot application properties in JSON configuration file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure, azure-application-insights

I am integrating Azure Application Insight service into my Spring Boot application.
`src/main/resources/applicationinsights.json` is being used for configuration. Not sure how to inject environment variables into it.
I tried this

*applicationinsights.json*

```
{
  "connectionString": "InstrumentationKey=${appInsightInstrumentationKey};IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
}
```

where `appInsightInstrumentationKey` is available as part of Spring environment variables.

This throws an error

> Illegal character in path
> at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:883)
> at reactor.netty.http.HttpOperations.resolvePath(HttpOperations.java:429)

Which means the variables is not getting repalced by the actual vaule. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Create a configmap ( YAML) and read from the values yamls.
In values YAML set it like below
 InstrumentationKey: ${appInsightInstrumentationKey}

Comment: @MohitSharma from what I understand this solution is more in context of Kubernetes. I am looking for a solution in context of Spring.

Answer (score 0):

***I have reproduced your requirement and could load configurations from the Json file in spring boot as shown below:***

1. Create an `Application.json` file in *Resources* folder and also META-INF directory.  Create a file called `spring.factories` inside the META-INF directory and add below configuration:

```
org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourceLoader=com.example.demo.JsonPropertySourceLoader
```

[image]

2. Create a `.json` file and add below code:

```json
{
"server.port":9080,
"testdata1":"testing",
"valuesMap":"{key1: '1', key2: '2', key3: '3'}"
}
```

[image]

3. Create a class called `JsonPropertySourceLoader` which will extend  `YAMLPropertySourceLoader` class present in the below package:

```
import  org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader;
```

```java
public  class  JsonPropertySourceLoader extends  YamlPropertySourceLoader  {
@Override
public  String[]  getFileExtensions()  {
return  new  String[]  {  "json"  };
}
}
```

[image]

4. *Create a rest controller class with the below code:*

```java
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public  class  DemoApplication  {

@Value("${testdata1}")
private  String  testData1;

@Value("#{${valuesMap}}")
private  Map<String,  Integer>  valuesMap;

@GetMapping("/")
public  String  echo()  {
System.out.println("Iterating the map....");
for  (Map.Entry<String,  Integer>  entry  :  valuesMap.entrySet())  {
System.out.println("Key = "  +  entry.getKey()
+  ", Value = "  +  entry.getValue());
}
return  testData1;
}
public  static  void  main(String[]  args)  {
SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class,  args);
}
}
```

**Response:**

Fetching the value from json configuration file.

[image]

***Refer to my [github repo](https://github.com/PravallikaKothaveerannagari/json_config) for complete code.***

Comment: I don't need to read properties from JSON file but rather inject values from environment variables to JSON config file at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to find a way to achieve this, but it doesn't look like there is a quick way to do this within spring.

But you can inject the variables using docker-compose.yml by specifying the environment variable:

```
APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING: "InstrumentationKey=..."
```

See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-config).

Seem to works fine in docker-compose.yml but doesn't work when I specify in application.yml